# How can I download an Openstreetmap.com map to be editable into Illustrator ? Any experience on that?

Tags: macos, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to design a cycling map for the town I'm living in, and trying to rely on Openstreetmap.com that has a Cycling Map layer. I've found many explanations on how to do it, but there is always something missing, required additional software (Viking, or other open source) that I'm not able to install on Mac OS. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "share" feature of https://www.openstreetmap.org/ to download an editable `.svg` file.

Note that such an image will most likely be © OpenStreetMap contributors, requiring you to adhere to the terms of the ODbL (basically: if you use the image, let people know how and where you got it).